# Noise-cancellation with undirected microphones and different amplifiers

Tags: c, audio, cancellation, noise-reduction

I have the following setup https://sketchfab.com/show/7e2912f5f8794a7b96ef3ac5930e090a (It's a 3d viewer, use your mouse to view all angles)

The box has two nondirectional electret microphones(black dots). On the ground there are some elements falling down like water or similar(symbolized by the sphere) and creating noises. On top, someone is speaking in the box. Distances are roughly accurate, so the mouth is pretty close.

Inside the box there are two different amplifiers(but the same electret microphones) with two different amplification circuits(the mouth-one is louder in general and has some normalization circuitry integrated. Long story short, I can record this into a raw audio file with 44100 Hz, 16Bit and Stereo, while the left channel is the upper, the right channel is the lower microphone amplifier output.

Goal is to - even though the electret microphones are not directed and even though there are different amplifiers - subtract the lower microphone(facing the ground) from the upper microphone(facing the speaker) to have noise cancellation.

I tried(With Datei being the raw-filename). This includes a high or low pass filter and a routine to put the final result back into a raw mono file (%s.neu.raw)

The problem is - well - undefinable distortion. I can hear my voice but it's not bearable at all. If you need a sample I can upload one.

EDIT: New code.

```
static void *substractf( char *Datei)
{
  char ergebnis[80];                                                  
  sprintf(ergebnis,"%s.neu.raw",Datei);
  FILE* ausgabe = fopen(ergebnis, "wb");
  FILE* f = fopen(Datei, "rb");                    
  if (f == NULL)
    return;
  double g = 0.1;
  double RC = 1.0/(1215*2*3.14);
  double dt = 1.0/44100;
  double alpha = dt/(RC+dt);
  double noise_gain = 18.0;
  double voice_gain = 1.0;
  struct {
    uint8_t noise_lsb;
    int8_t  noise_msb;
    uint8_t voice_lsb;
    int8_t  voice_msb;
  } sample;  

  while (fread(&sample, sizeof sample, 1, f) == 1) 
  {
    int16_t noise_source = sample.noise_msb * 256 + sample.noise_lsb;
    int16_t voice_source = sample.voice_msb * 256 + sample.voice_lsb;
    double signal, difference_voice_noise;            
    difference_voice_noise = voice_gain*voice_source - noise_gain*noise_source;
    signal = (1.0 - alpha)*signal + alpha*difference_voice_noise;  
    putc((char) ( (signed)signal       & 0xff),ausgabe);
    putc((char) (((signed)signal >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);  
  }   
  fclose(f);                             
  fclose(ausgabe);  
  char output[300];                                 
  sprintf(output,"rm -frv \"%s\"",Datei);
  system(output);
}
```

Comment: `while(wo !=EOF) { wo = getc(f);` is a small problem.  `wo` needs to be immediately tested for EOF after the `getc()`.  Doing the test beforehand let's `wo` equal EOF for 1 loop.

Comment: @chux I don't understand. What should it look like?

Comment: `while ((c = getc(f)) != EOF) {`

Comment: 2 ideas: 1) use `double` instead of `float`.  Well A/D converted sounds is on the order of 20-22 bits fidelity, (float has 23) but various mathematical noise can be noticed at times.  2) Instead of subtracting, add.  Sometimes the mic's wires are crossed and you need to undo that in software.

Comment: 2 more ideas: 1)u se `r-g*l-r` ( or `r+g*l`) instead of `r - fileter_l`. (do the filtering _After_ the subtraction) Use `struct { int16_t l,r; } sample; while (fread(sample, sizeof sample, f) > 0) {` to simplify all the byte splicing you are doing.

Comment: @chux This is confusing. Please create a pastebin with your changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideas too big for a comment.

1) Looks like OP is filtering the `l` signal `jetzt = vorher + (alpha*(l - vorher))` and then subtracting the `r` with `dif = r - g*jetzt`.  It seems to make more sense to subtract `l` and `r` first and apply that difference to the filter.

```
float signal = 0.0; (outside loop)
...
float dif;
// Differential (with gain adjustments)
dif = gain_l*l - gain_r*r;
// Low pass filter (I may have this backwards)
signal = (1.0 - alpha)*signal + alpha*dif;
// I am not certain if diff or signal should be written
// but testing  limit would be useful.
if ((dif > 32767) || (dif < -32767)) report();
int16_t sig = dif;
// I see no reason for the following test
// if (dif != 0)
putc((char) ( (unsigned)dif       & 0xff),ausgabe);
putc((char) (((unsigned)dif >> 8) & 0xff),ausgabe);
```

2) The byte splicing may be off.   Suggested simplification

```
// This assumes incoming data is little endian, 
// Maybe data is in big endian and _that_ is OP problem?
struct {
  uint8_t l_lsb;
  int8_t  l_msb;
  uint8_t r_lsb;
  int8_t  r_msb;
} sample;
...
while (fread(&sample, sizeof sample, 1, f) == 1) {
   int16_t left  = sample.l_msb * 256 + sample.l_lsb;
   int16_t right = sample.r_msb * 256 + sample.r_lsb;
```

3) Use of `float` vs. `double`.  Usually the more limiting `float` creates computational noise, but the magnitude of OP's complaint suggest that this issue is unlikely *the* problem.  Still worth considering.

4) Endian of the 16-bit samples may be backwards.  Further, depending on A/D encoding the samples may be 16-bit unsigned rather than 16-bit signed.

5) The phase of the 2 signals could be 180 out from each other due to wiring and mic pick-up.  Is so try `diff = gain_l*l + gain_r*r`.

Comment: Okay. I included it and created http://pastebin.com/Ly2R6tJA Unfortunately, no matter whether I use gain_l*l + gain_r*r or gain_r*r - gain_l*l or gain_l*l - gain_r*r, the spikes always add up. What would the while (fread(&sample, ... part look like to delay one channel as squeamish ossifrage suggested?

Comment: You can find a sample original file for reference at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2f1564appiY1owNHdoNHVpekU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I want to politely remind you of your reply. Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. What is ping?

Comment: @Gewinn Note: Per the discussion of @squeamish, subtracting a 2nd signal only makes sense up to a certain frequency.  This _supports_ your `jetzt = vorher + (alpha*(l - vorher)); dif = r - g*jetzt;`.

Comment: @Gewinn Are you reading a ".raw" file that has pairs of 2-byte samples **or** are you reading the a ".wav" as you have linked in your above comment?  Your code does _not_ appear to be parsing a ".wav" file correctly.

Comment: I am reading the raw file I uploaded here as a sample. This is the exact type of raw file this function gets.

Comment: Yes, I converted it for easier playing. Do you need the raw file? I thought it was about phase shift and amplitudes to find out the reason why whatever I do with gain_r*r and gain_l*l does not eliminate the noise signal. For testing purposes, I currently have this code: http://pastebin.com/wip9vQTA - If you need the real raw, here it goes https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2f1564appia1R4MEdSajY0aWM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: There used to be a time when my input file had long pauses without any information. I wanted to cut them out. BTW using `signal = (1.0 - alpha)*signal + alpha*dif;`, I seem to properly subtract the channels but I also lose a lot of fidelity. Why is that and how to compensate? As a comparison, I use the center-channel-extractor of adobe audition with the "Right" (as in right and left) option and I notice a much better fidelity while at the same removal of the noise... These are my settings: http://i.imgur.com/mC6DyFn.jpg

Comment: Your `r` channel (1st byte pair) has a much weaker signal than `l` (2nd pair).  You say "left channel is the upper" which I think should be the louder.  Right is background, Left is voice, please confirm.  You filter the left channel only.  I think you should be filtering the right (background) instead.  Further, try using `double` rather than `float`.  GTG

Comment: I switched up the channels. BTW you are talking about taking out the dif != 0. Did you notice that my current code is http://pastebin.com/wip9vQTA ? I will edit my main post with the current code so everybody can relate instead of pastebin, as this seems more appropriate.

Comment: Problem is still: I seem to properly subtract the channels but I also lose a lot of fidelity. Why is that and how to compensate? As a comparison, I use the center-channel-extractor of adobe audition with the "Right" (as in right and left) option and I notice a much better fidelity while at the same removal of the noise...

Comment: @OP Reviewed your edits.  Suspect your noise gain should be about 18.

Comment: @OP  Also deleting comments that do not pertain to the technical aspects.

Comment: @Gewinn Your latest post is easiest to understand.  Have to go now, but some parting thoughts: Maybe have independent filters on left/right? I'm thinking that the noise needs a lower cut-off frequency based on "squeamish ossifrage". I picked a gain of 18 (18.85) as that made the noise signal most _like_ the voice in a constructive way - assuming the (voice - 18.85*noise) are then the true noise.

Comment: Updated. What does "Maybe have independent filters on left/right?" look like in code? Also, what does `signal = (1.0 - alpha)*signal + alpha*difference_voice_noise;` do exactly?

Comment: `SignalVoice = (1.0 - AlphaVoice)*SignalVoice + AlphaVoice*VoiceSource; SignalNoise = (1.0 - AlphaNoise)*SignalNoise + AlphaNoise*Noise; diff = GainVoice*SignalVoice - GainNoise*SignalNoise;`  You posted "signal = (1.0 - alpha)*signal + alpha*dif".  I found it confusing as it seemed to combine the filtering and gains into 1 step that was not clear how to adjust.

Comment: What do you suggest for CUTOFF_VOICE and CUTOFF_NOISE in `double RC_VOICE = 1.0/(CUTOFF_VOICE*2*3.14);` and `double RC_NOISE = 1.0/(CUTOFF_NOISE*2*3.14);`?

Comment: Suggest CUTOFF_NOISE lower than CUTOFF_VOICE.  CUTOFF_NOISE needs to take into account the `d2-d1` as any signal above that half frequency (e.g.  1650), even if `SignalNoise` is picked-up with high fidelity, makes no sense to add/subtract with SignalVoice as @squeamish ossifrage details.  `CUTOFF_VOICE` depends on `SignalVoice` alone, maybe something like 18kHz?

Comment: So you recommend CUTOFF_NOISE = 9000 and CUTOFF_VOICE = 18000?

Comment: @Gewinn 1) The values I listed are illustrative.  You will need to determine the bet values. 2) Are your files still "voice but it's not bearable"?  Adjusting these cut-off values will not solve a "not bearable" issue - something else is wrong.

Comment: No. The voice is clearly audible now(I use CUTOFF_NOISE = 16000 and CUTOFF_VOICE = 18000), I am currently optimizing to have as little noise as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't take differences of path length into consideration.

The path difference *d*<sub>2</sub> – *d*<sub>1</sub> between the sound source and the two mics corresponds to a time delay of (*d*<sub>2</sub> – *d*<sub>1</sub>) / *v*, where *v* is the speed of sound (330 m/s).

[image: Illustration of path difference with two microphones]

Suppose *d*<sub>2</sub> – *d*<sub>1</sub> is equal to 10 cm. In this case, any sound wave whose frequency is a multiple of 3300 Hz (i.e., whose period is a multiple of (0.10/330) seconds) will be at exactly the same phase at both microphones. This is how you want things to be at all frequencies.

However, a sound wave at an odd multiple of half that frequency (1650 Hz, 4950 Hz, 8250 Hz, etc.) will have changed in phase by 180° by the time it reaches the second mic. As a result, your subtraction operation will actually have the opposite effect — you'll be boosting these frequencies instead of making them quieter.

The end result will be similar to what you get if you push all the alternate sliders on a graphic equaliser in opposite directions. This is probably what you're experiencing now.

Try estimating the length of this path difference and delaying the samples in one channel by a corresponding amount. At a sampling rate of 44100 Hz, one centimetre corresponds to about 0.75 samples. If the sound source is moving around, then things get a bit complicated. You'll have to find a way of estimating the path difference dynamically from the audio signals themselves.

Comment: RC should encompass path difference, especially 1215

Comment: You can find a sample original file for reference at https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bx2f1564appiY1owNHdoNHVpekU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Great graphics, and explanation.